# Mysql ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode issue - Pick single Image URL(any) for each Album

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

I need help in a mysql query, here are the details:

Three Tables, Album_Master , Album_Photo_Map, Photo_Details

Album_Master Table Structure

```
album_id(P) | album_name | user_id(F)
1               abc           1
2               xyz           1
3               pqr           1
4               e3e           2
```

Album_Photo_Map Table Structure

```
auto_id(P) | album_id(F) | photo_id
1             1              123
2             1              124
3             2              123 
4             2              125
5             1              127
6             3              127
```

Photo_Details Table Structure

```
auto_id(P) | image_id(F) | image_url
1               123          http....
2               124          http....
3               125          http...
```

I want to write a query to get the album name with image url for user_id 1
The output I am expecting here is

```
album_id | album_name | image_url
1            abc          http.. (either 123 or 124 or 127 - only one url)
2            xyz          http.. (either 123 or 125 - only one)
3            pqr          http.. (127 only)
```

The query I am using is taking too much time to execute, almost 8s.

```
SELECT A.album_id
     , A.album_name
     , D.image_url 
  from Album_Master A
     , Album_Photo_Map E 
  LEFT 
  JOIN Photo_Details D 
    ON (D.image_id = (
      SELECT P.photo_id 
        FROM Album_Photo_Map P
           , Photo_Details Q 
       WHERE P.photo_id = Q.image_id 
         AND P.album_id = E.album_id limit 0,1)
       ) 
 WHERE A.album_id = E.album_id 
   AND A.user_id = 1 
 group 
    by A.album_id
     , E.album_id
     , D.image_url;
```

I am looking for an optimize version of the query, any help will be really appreciated. If I use `image_url` in group by it is creating multiple records, also if I remove `D.image_url` it gives me error

> D.image_url' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Note: user can assign one photo in multiple albums, result should pick only one photo per album, there might be 100 of photos in an album.

Comment: In addition, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query.

Comment: Will you predetermine the "one photo", perhaps a 'representative' or 'favorite' from the album? (easier)  Or do you want a random photo?  (harder)

Comment: @RickJames, just a random photo

Comment: @Strawberry I'll try to create a db-fiddle for better R&D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it doesn't matter which url it should include in resultset then you can just do group by `album_id` only and you are good to go.

```
SELECT 
    A.album_id, A.album_name, D.image_url 
FROM album_master A
INNER JOIN album_photo_map P ON A.album_id = P.album_id
INNER JOIN photo_details D ON P.photo_id = D.image_id
GROUP BY A.album_id;
```

Note: If you want album info even there is no photo attached to it then use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` in query.

**[Functional Dependency Issue due to ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY%20SQL%20mode,are%20functionally%20dependent%20on%20them.)**

> MySQL 5.7.5 and later implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them

> Specific Issue: D.image_url' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

***Solution 1:***
If possible use `aggregate` function for the other columns which are not included in `group by` clause.

***Solution 2:***
If you know that, for a given data set, each `album_id` value in fact uniquely determines the `image_url` value that means `image_url` is effectively functionally dependent on `album_id`. So you can do

```
SELECT 
    A.album_id, A.album_name, ANY_VALUE(D.image_url) AS image_url 
FROM album_master A
INNER JOIN album_photo_map P ON A.album_id = P.album_id
INNER JOIN photo_details D ON P.photo_id = D.image_id
GROUP BY A.album_id;
```

***Solution 3: Alternatively Disable `only_full_group_by` in mysql***

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));

SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

A more info check [`Solve Query Failures Regarding ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL MODE`](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/05/13/solve-query-failures-regarding-only_full_group_by-sql-mode/)

Comment: I tried the query you suggested but mysql saying "image_url" is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause, So I added ```GROUP BY A.album_id,D.image_url``` both, but now getting list of all images in each row as because each image_url is different. Also I added A.user_id = 1 in Where Clause.

Comment: Here is the updated query, but not getting the expected result: ```SELECT 
    A.album_id, A.album_name, D.image_url 
FROM album_master A
INNER JOIN album_photo_map P ON A.album_id = P.album_id
INNER JOIN photo_details D ON P.photo_id = D.image_id 
WHERE A.user_id = 1 
GROUP BY A.album_id,D.image_url;```

Comment: Are you working with laravel and recently updated the version? or it is database only. Please run this query in Heidi SQL or PHPMyAdmin to verify.

Comment: I am using Sequel Pro with my localhost database.

Comment: By adding D.image_url in GROUP BY clause, you are asking MySQL to create separate records for each album and URL. So it won't return you the exact result. Please provide the environment details(MySQL version, any PHP or other languages from where you are executing this query)

Comment: MySQL version 5.7.27, I am not in PHP, it's in NodeJS/ExpressJS. And the error I am getting while executing the query is ```D.image_url' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by``` if I didn't add D.image_url in the Group By clause

Comment: @SudipPal, disable only_full_group_by  mode in mysql.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198425/discussion-between-jitendra-yadav-and-sudip-pal).

Comment: Note that 'random' and 'indeterminate' aren't quite same thing - although I'm not really qualified to explain the difference.