# Error while running Laravel 4 Eloquent query in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm converting my Laravel 4 code into Laravel 8. My Eloquent query works fine in Laravel 4 but in Laravel 8, its getting following error. The error causing Model is `WPModel`.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'compliance.work_processes.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select users.fullname AS OwnerName, `work_processes`.*, AVG( audit_assignments.audit_compliance ) AS compliance from `work_processes` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `work_processes`.`wp_owner_id` inner join `audit_assignments` on `audit_assignments`.`wp_id` = `work_processes`.`id` where `wp_location` = PRT and audit_assignments.audit_compliance IS NOT NULL and `wp_active` = Y group by `work_processes`.`wp_name` order by `updated_at` desc)
```

***HomeController***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\WPModel;
use App\Models\AuditAssignModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function showWPs($loc = 'PRT')
    {
        $searchFilters = array('fromdate' => '', 'todate' => '', 'name' => '', 'type' => '');
        $admin = 0; // identified if an admin interface or homepage --- homepage => 0, adminpage => 1
        if(!in_array($loc, array('PRT','PNG','NZL')))
            $loc = 'PRT';       

        $work_processes = WPModel::location($loc)
                                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'work_processes.wp_owner_id')
                                    ->Join('audit_assignments', 'audit_assignments.wp_id', '=', 'work_processes.id')
                                    ->select(DB::raw('users.fullname AS OwnerName'), 'work_processes.*', DB::raw('AVG( audit_assignments.audit_compliance ) AS compliance'))
                                    ->whereRaw('audit_assignments.audit_compliance IS NOT NULL') //
                                    ->activeWPs()
                                    ->groupBy('work_processes.wp_name')
                                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                                    ->get();//

        $last_compliances = AuditAssignModel::select('wp_id', 'audit_compliance', 'audit_assignments.updated_at')
                                    ->leftJoin('work_processes', 'audit_assignments.wp_id', '=', 'work_processes.id')
                                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'ASC')
                                    ->activeWPs()
                                    ->completedAudits()
                                    ->get();
        foreach ($last_compliances as $key => $compliance) {
            $arr_last_compliance[$compliance->wp_id]['last_compliance'] = $compliance->audit_compliance;
            $arr_last_compliance[$compliance->wp_id]['updated_at'] = $compliance->updated_at;
        }
        $last_compliances = $arr_last_compliance;

        return View::make('home', compact('work_processes', 'admin', 'loc', 'searchFilters', 'last_compliances'));
    }
}
?>
```

***WPModel***

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class WPModel extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'work_processes';
    protected $guarded = array('id');
    protected $softDelete = true;
    
    /**
     * Get the Work Process Start Date formatted.
     *
     * @param  timestamp  $value
     * @return timestamp
     */
    public function getWpStartdateAttribute( $value ) {     
        return (new Carbon($value))->format('d-M-Y');
    }

    /**
     * Get the Work Process Created Date formatted.
     *
     * @param  timestamp  $value
     * @return timestamp
     */
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute( $value ) {       
        return (new Carbon($value))->format('d-M-Y H:i');
    }

    // declaring one-to-many relationship
    public function relatedWPAQs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('WPAQModel', 'wp_id');
    }

    public function relatedUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('UserModel', 'wp_owner_id');
    }
    public function relatedAudits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('AuditAssignModel', 'wp_id');
    }

    public function getUserNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value;
    }
    public function getWPName()
    {
        return $this->wp_name;
    }
    public function getWPOwner()
    {
        return $this->relatedUsers->fullname;
    }
    public function getDates()
    {
        return array('created_at', 'updated_at');
    }
    public function scopeActiveWPs($query)
    {
        return $query->where('wp_active', '=', 'Y'); 
    }
    public function scopeWPType($query, $wp_type = NULL)
    {
        if(in_array($wp_type, array('M','F','D')))
            return $query->where('wp_type', '=', $wp_type);
        else
            return;
    }
    public function scopeNameWP($query, $wp_name = NULL)
    {
        if(!empty($wp_name))
            return $query->where('work_processes.wp_name', 'like', '%'.$wp_name.'%'); 
    }
    public function scopeLocation($query, $loc)
    {
        return $query->where('wp_location', '=', $loc); 
    }
    public static function getWpType($wp_type)
    {
        if($wp_type)
        {
            $arr_wp_type = array('M' => 'Maintenance', 'F' => 'Field', 'D' => 'Drilling');
            return $arr_wp_type[$wp_type];
        }
        else{
            return "All Types";
        }
    }
    public static function getWpFrequency($wp_frequency)
    {
        if($wp_frequency)
        {
            $arr_wp_frequency = array('B' => 'Bi-Monthly', 'M' => 'Monthly', 'Q' => 'Quarterly');
            return $arr_wp_frequency[$wp_frequency];
        }else{
            return;
        }

    }
    public static function getWpLocation($wp_location)
    {
        if($wp_location)
        {
            $arr_wp_location = array('PRT' => 'Perth', 'PNG' => 'PNG', 'NZL' => 'New Zealand');
            return $arr_wp_location[$wp_location];
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment part of the query like below, it does work but with limited data ofcoarse. But again, in Laravel 4, this query is working just like a breeze.

```
        $work_processes = WPModel::location($loc)
//                                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'work_processes.wp_owner_id')
//                                    ->Join('audit_assignments', 'audit_assignments.wp_id', '=', 'work_processes.id')
//                                    ->select(DB::raw('users.fullname AS OwnerName'), 'work_processes.*', DB::raw('AVG( audit_assignments.audit_compliance ) AS compliance'))
//                                    ->whereRaw('audit_assignments.audit_compliance IS NOT NULL') //
                                    ->activeWPs()
//                                  ->groupBy('work_processes.wp_name')
                                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                                    ->get();//
```

***Server Configurations***

```
Apache/2.4.43 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.8
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.8
PHP extension: mysqli curl mbstring 
PHP version: 7.4.8
```

Comment: I think it is not an issue with laravel, it is for `mysql`. Did you updated the version to mysql8. If so please check `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mysql mode

Comment: awsome. Here's what I did and it worked. ```DB::statement("SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));");```. You can post this as an answer so I accept it.

Comment: Yes. disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY resolved my issue. But I'm not sure if I should do it globally or not. Upvoted though on the other post you mentioned.

Comment: Don't do that `globally` if other guys will not be using that. One more thing is it is recommended to modify your query so it will support `full group by` join. If you want i can give reference for that too. So you need not to disable full group by.

Comment: check the updated answer and also accept as duplicate if it is the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640162/mysql-only-full-group-by-mode-issue-pick-single-image-urlany-for-each-album/57640534#57640534