# Laravel GroupBy work in mysql but throws error in MariaDB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I'm Running the following query without any problem in MySQL (5.7.21) Database but this query throws error on my hosting server database which is MariaDB (10.1.47-MariaDB) and I don't have super permission to change the `sql mode`.

```
$projects =  V2Project::leftJoin('v2_project_locations as v2pl', 'v2pl.project_id', 'v2_projects.id')
             ->leftJoin('v2_locations as v2l', 'v2l.id', 'v2pl.location_id')
             ->selectRaw('v2_projects.id, v2_projects.name, group_concat(v2l.name) as locations')
             ->withDepartmentInMind()
             ->onlyAuthorizedObjects();

if($by_current_step == true) {
    $projects = $projects->where('current_step', 'plan');
}

if($search_val) {
    $projects = $projects->whereIn('v2_projects.id', $search_val);
}

$projects = $projects->groupBy('v2_projects.id')->paginate(10); 
$projects->appends(Input::except('page', '_token'));
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'pm_form_moe.v2_projects.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select v2_projects.id, v2_projects.name from `v2_projects` group by `v2_projects`.`id`)
```

I also tried to add every column, but I need the functionality the same as mySQL without adding all columns.

Comment: I guess your mysql server is an older version according to this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591606/how-to-resolve-isnt-in-group-by-error-in-mysql-query/33591759

Comment: Which versions you are using MySQL / MariaDB

Comment: `groupBy('v2_projects.id, v2_projects.name')`

Comment: MariaDB Version: 10.1.47-MariaDB, MySQL Version: 5.7.21

Comment: `groupBy('v2_projects.id, v2_projects.name')` I tried this solution by it will throw error for the next column of `v2_projects` table.

Comment: Add all columns which are present in output without aggregating into grouping expression. Or backward, remove excess columns from output list.

Comment: post the output from select @@sql_mode; if there set ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY remove it. see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/

Comment: the output is: `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mysql ONLY\_FULL\_GROUP\_BY mode issue - Pick single Image URL(any) for each Album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57640162/mysql-only-full-group-by-mode-issue-pick-single-image-urlany-for-each-album)  check solution 3 but recommended 1 & 2

Comment: If the query works fine in mariaDB engine, try edit the config/database.php in your laravel project and change 'strict' => false, in DB driver array

Comment: The query doesnt work with mariadb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, then decide what to remove from your `SELECT` or what to add to the `GROUP BY`.  Don't worry about setting the flag; your code is bad and needs to be fixed.  And it was bad in the older version when it did not complain.

(If you show us the generated SQL, we can discuss it further.)